# WSO2 API Manager 3.0 Session Not Logging Out of Publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

**Situation:**
Our instance of WSO2 API Manager 3.0 is not logging out via the Publisher. Logout *does* work via the Store.

**Details:**
When a user clicks the logout link in the Publisher they are prompted with an OpenID Connect Logout prompt: "Do you want to logout?". Upon clicking 'Yes' the user is returned the Publisher with the session still active.

The same user *is* able to logout via the Store. When they logout from the Store their Publisher sessions is also logged out.

The problem arises only when they attempt to logout of the Publisher session.

[image]

**Configuration:**
Our WSO2 instance is connected to an Oracle Cloud IAM. 
The callback settings for both the Publisher and Store are the same.

e.g. https://our-iam-server.our-companny.com/signout.html

Navigation to Store settings (working):

Identity (menu bar in Carbon) -> Service Providers -> List -> **admin_admin_store** -> Edit -> Inbound Authentication Configuration -> OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration -> Edit -> Enable OIDC Backchannel Logout -> Backchannel Logout Url

Navigation to Publisher settings (not working):

Identity (menu bar in Carbon) -> Service Providers -> List -> **admin_admin_publisher** -> Edit -> Inbound Authentication Configuration -> OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration -> Edit -> Enable OIDC Backchannel Logout -> Backchannel Logout Url

Value is the same on both pages:

[image]

We customized the JavaScript on both the Store and Publisher with the following:

```
var str = document.referrer;
var substr =  "oauth2_logout_consent.do"
if(str.includes(substr)){
    alert("relocating to https://[IAM-hostname]/signout.html");
    window.location.replace("https://[IAM-hostname]/signout.html");
}
```

In the Store, the 'alert' block is reached and logout is successful.
In the Publisher, the 'alert' block is never reached.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Upgrade to API-Manager version 3.1.

Reason: Version 3.0 does not have the 'Logout Endpoint URL' parameter as show below. Version 3.1 does.

[image]